# How can I prove that $4^{n} + 5$ is divisible by $3$.

Tags: induction

I have trying to prove that  $4^{n} + 5$.

I've already proved the base case, so I'm working on the inductive step.

I've done the following:

$4^{n} + 5$

$4^{n+1} + 5$

$4*4^{n} + 5$

But I am unsure where to go from here to prove that it is divisible by 3 since I am unsure how to get a $3$ or multiple of $3$ from this.

Comment: Use congruences modulo $3$.

Comment: $$4^n\equiv1^n\pmod3$$

Comment: Alternatively, note that $4=(3+1)$ so $4^{n+1}+5 = 4\cdot 4^n + 5 = 3\cdot 4^n + (4^n + 5)$

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you

Comment: Recall: $a^n-b^n=(a-b)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+....b^{n-1})$; Now write $4^n-1+1+5=(4^n-1^n) +6$;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From @JMoravitz and continuing from the question above,

$4 * 4^{n} + 5$

$(3 + 1)4^{n} + 5$

$3(4^{n}) + (4^{n} + 5)$

From the base case, we know $(4^{n} + 5)$ is divisible by 3, and trivially $3(4^{n})$ is also divisible by 3.

$Q.E.D.$

Answer (score 1):

No need for induction:
$$\begin{align}5+4^n&=5+(3+1)^n\\
&=5+\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}3^k\\
&=5+1+\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}3^k\\
&=3\cdot\left(2+\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}3^{k-1}\right).
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

$4\cdot 4^n+5=4(4^n+5)-15$ and both $4^n+5,15$ are divisible by $3$.

Answer (score 0):

It is $$4^n+5\equiv 1^n+2\equiv 1+2\equiv 0 \mod 3$$

Answer (score 0):

$4^n +5 \equiv 4^n - 1$ mod $3$.

$4^n-1 = (2^n - 1)(2^n + 1)$. Either $2^n - 1$, or $2^n + 1$ is divisible by $3$, because among three successive integers (in this case $2^n-1, 2^n, 2^n + 1$) exactly one of them is divisible by $3$, and clearly, $2^n$ is not one of them.

More specifically, if $n$ is odd, then $2^n + 1$ is divisible by $3$, otherwise $2^n - 1$ is divisible by $3$.

Answer (score 0):

You may use mathematical induction to solve this easily.

Let us assume $4^n+5=3k$
$$4^{n+1}+5=4{\cdot}4^{n}+5$$
$$=4{\cdot}4^{n}+20-15$$
$$=4(4^{n}+5)-15$$
$$=4(3k)-3{\cdot}5$$
$$=3(4k-5)$$
$$=3m$$

Hence $4^n+5$ is divisible by 3 for all n.

Answer (score 0):

You can prove that using induction

We suppose that $4^n + 5 \equiv 3$ is true

Induction base: $n = 1 \Longrightarrow 4^1 + 5 = 9 \equiv 3$ - true.

Induction transition: let $k = n+1 \Longrightarrow 4^k + 5 = 4^{n+1}+5 = 4 \cdot 4^n + 5 = 3\cdot4^n + 4^n + 5$

$3 \cdot 4^n \equiv 3, \ \ 4^n + 5 \equiv 3$

Hence $4^{n+1} + 5\equiv3 \Longrightarrow \ 4^n + 5 \equiv 3$